# Storing sqlite databsae in the iphone. Unable to get it back.

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, ios4

Not sure what the mistake i am doing. Please suggest. 
In my application i am creating a database, and when i relaunch the application next time, the database is not seen. I found what the problem is, but not the solution .

```
 NSArray *dirPaths;
    NSString *docsDirectory;
    NSString *databasePath;
    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    docsDirectory = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"MYDATABASE.db"]];
    NSLog (@" Database Path : %@ ",databasePath);
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
```

Unfortunately, i get the following path printed.

```
Database Path : /var/mobile/Applications/27C4C465-0D65-44AA-BBB3-693G4D1CDD4D/Documents/MYDATABASE.db
```

When i reinvoke the application i get the different path ie: 27C4C465-0D65-44AA-BBB3-693G4D1CDD4 is replaced with some other value, that's why it could not able to locate the database properly.

How can i resolve this issue? Kindly suggest.

Comment: That long hex string is the App's UUID, which shouldn't change between runs.  Is this during development or in production?

Comment: trojanfoe, it is in the development.

Comment: you want to locate the databese... in finder?